# ignore nginx port to add in url? When i change nginx port

Tags: node.js, nginx

I want to use nginx on different port. If i am running nginx on default port(80) and trying to use by the url (100.100.7.60) this is working fine.

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name 100.100.7.60;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://100.100.7.60:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

}

But when i am changing nginx port 80 to 8080 or to any port. If now i am trying by (100.100.7.60). I am unable to run node.js application. Now if i want to run application my url should be like (100.100.7.60:8080).

```
server {
listen 8080;
server_name 100.100.7.60;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://100.100.7.60:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

}

Can anyone explain me what is problem? I want to change port number. But i do not want to add (:8080) in url. I want to make same url after changing port number

Answer (score 0):

If you want to listen on a different port, you cannot exclude the port number from the URL. When you enter `100.100.7.60` into a browser, the protocol is HTTP and the port is 80 by default.

There is a (very bad) workaround to this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 100.100.7.60;

    return 301 http://100.100.7.60:8080;
}
```

This will redirect **ALL** traffic on port 80 to port 8080, which is (I assume) not what you want.

Instead, you should configure your DNS to point to this server using a subdomain eg `myapp.example.com` and then listen on 80 port with that server name to serve your app.